# For loop in while loop

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

can I put a for loop in while loop? For example:

```
while($end = 1)
{
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($match); $i++)
  {
    $mathcas = $match[$i][1];
  }
}
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in while/for loop? Are you looking for pros/cons? or how to implement while/for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is perfectly possible, I strongly recommend avoiding the particular construct you are trying...

If you find the element you are lloking for, just `break` the `for` loop and you will be done!

Edit: and please use `==` for comparisons!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. And now for some padding...

Edit: on second thought, if your internal loop does not change the value of $end, you're looking at an infinite loop.

Comment: Actually, even if he does change `$end` inside the loop, it'll still be infinite. :o)

Comment: Indeed, `=` vs. `==` strikes again!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.
though in the example you gave the outer while loop will either never end or never run